# Guidelines for posting a shameless plug as an answer

Tags: discussion

I've posted links to things I've developed or worked on in some answers. I always qualify the answer by saying that it is a "shameless plug" and also that there are probably other alternative solutions. In general, I'm *very careful* to make it *not* look like the post is self-aggrandizing. I also only post a plug if I feel that it is an actual solution, and not for "fame and/or fortune". Sometimes I get downvotes without any explanation, but overall reaction has been positive.

Still, I'm wondering; are there any general guidelines to posting a solution where the poster may have a sort of "conflict of interest"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the 3rd-last paragraph titled ["May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?" in the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).

Also, search meta for "[self-promotion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=self-promotion)" (which can be OK) and "[astroturfing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=astroturfing)" (which is not OK).

Comment: The help article has been reworded since, but the last paragraph still talks about self promotion.

Answer (score 5):

Where there is a conflict of interest, I would suggest a full, clear and frank disclosure of both the conflict, and how you stand to gain from your recommendation. The qualifications you use are of value in contributing to this disclosure. I don't see any problem with recommending something as a actual solution where there is such conflict, so long as there is such disclosure.

I have not been in precisely your situation, but on the one answer I gave that recommended a particular commercial product, I was very careful to state that I had no connection with the product, except as a very satisfied customer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest avoiding the term “shameless plug” (which I see as chit chat) in favor of directly answering the question and, if your product was not directly asked about by name in the question, then I think you should state simply something like this at the end:

> **Disclosure**: I am the [position] at [company/team/etc] that [sells/develops/etc] the product [name] being advocated here.